# Things to know before buying a 1970's wooden house in Sweden?

Tags: floor, support

Looking at buying a wooden house in a forest in Sweden that has some moisture / floor strength issues. While I'll be getting a professional builder to help me inspect the potential floor damage, are there any other things I should be mindful of before purchasing the property?

Comment: If it is a completely wood house that would be unique.   Do you have pictures and what are you worried about?

Comment: If moisture issues, find them first.  Long term leaks might have ruin the supporting  wood.

Comment: The condition of the roof, the condition of the windows, the insulation

Comment: There are _gazillions_ of things you should know before buying a house...wooden or otherwise. Can you narrow it down to a specific question that can be answered here?

Comment: I agree with @gnicko. There isn't really anything worth NOT looking into when buying a house. Thus, the inverse question, which is what your asking is too broad, as you should check EVERYTHING.

Answer (score 3):

The 1960s through to the 1980s construction in Sweden was pretty simple. Most likely the frame is just 48mm x 98mm (2" x 4") framing with just 100mm of insulation. Exterior will likely be a bitumous sheet layer and cladding nailed straight to the frame, with either little or no air gap.

Most likely there will be some damage to the exterior cladding around the details, windows, bottom edges, roof line etc.

Floor strength is already compromised as the timbers are likely to be smaller in section that what would be used today. Ventilation will also be minimal and often blocked off.

Priority is as always, weatherproofing. Sorting out the roof and rainwater on and around the property.

If it's original, bank on replacing just about everything. Kitchen, bathrooms (which will not have very good membranes behind tiles etc.), electrics and plumbing, not to mention changing layouts and repairing all the interior surfaces and most likely replacing most of the trims.

Nothing mentioned above will come as a surprise to your carpenter though. It's all regular 'bread and butter' work for us here in Scandinavia.

Is the house on pillars or a walled/stone/concrete foundation?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is built on a plain rock (quite literally - I see the exposed rockface in the crawlspace), with a concrete foundation on top.

Comment: Yeah, that's ideal and very, very common. I've even seen houses with exposed rock faces left in finished basements/rooms, super cool look!